# Mostar dados da tabela PHP

Tags: php

Estou com um problema, queria mostrar os dados da tabela respetivos a consulta que é feita. Só consigo mostrar os dois valores dentro do ciclo for. O que quero é mostrar os dados fora do ciclo for, tipo guardar para um array e mostrar esse array.

```
for($y=2; $y>0; $y--){
                    $base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);                    
                    $requete    =   "SELECT id, title, start, end, description, jour, mois, annee, date 
                        FROM \"event\" 
                        WHERE jour=\"$i\"
                        AND id=$y";

                    $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);     
                    $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();

                    $result = "<label><b>$affiche[title]</b></label><br>";

                    echo $result;

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

crie fora o seu laço uma variável vazia do tipo Array. Em seguida dentro do for, utilize a função array_push para inserir no final da variável o resultado encontrado.
Para percorrer a variável utilize o foreach

```
$array_resultados = array();
for($y=2; $y>0; $y--){
                        $base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);                    
                        $requete    =   "SELECT id, title, start, end, description, jour, mois, annee, date 
                            FROM \"event\" 
                            WHERE jour=\"$i\"
                            AND id=$y";
                    $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);     
                    $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();
                    array_push($array_resultados, $affiche);

            }
foreach($array_resultados as $key =>$value){

                $echo "<label><b>".$value['title']."</b></label><br>";

}
```

Comment: Não consigo mostrar os dados na tabela.

Comment: Você deseja exibir os resultados EM uma tabela ou os resultados DE uma tabela?

Comment: Os resultados de uma tabela respetivos a consulta.